# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR on eclipse-cdt

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl-2

I was installed `SDL2` libs + `eclipse`, `eclipse-cdt` + `g++` to start developing some games on Eclipse IDE.

I'm on Debian. I installed it using the `apt`.

The project builds normally, but does not run. The following output comes from Console window

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
```

However, the generated binarie on `debug` folder runs normally if I execute it out of eclipse.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this;

open eclipse settings and try setting up environment variable  "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"  as "/run/user/1000" and apply.

open drop down menu near to "Run button" -->den open  "Run configuration" --> open  "Environment" -->> "new" >> variable as "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" and value as "/run/user/1000"

its worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the solution for this error. Exporting `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` before running eclipse apparently doesn't work.

I installed another version of Eclipse and it worked well (?)

Consider using more recent versions of eclipse-cdt than the repository's one